# Where is SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2012

I had SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on my laptop. I've installed SQL Server 2012 and have finally got SQL Server Data Tools to show up, so that I can create SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2010.

Although I've installed Management tools - *many times* - on two separate instances of SQL Server 2012, I can't find them in Programs and can't run them. The only SSMS program I can find runs SSMS 2008 R2.

I realise that common advice is to install SQL Server before Visual Studio, but I really don't want to uninstall Visual Studio, as this will bring a host of other problems.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I always go to run and type ssms.exe .. I accept I am lazy !

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite: Didn't work for me.  I had SSMS 2008R2 installed and recently installed SSMS 2012 as well.  Typing "ssms" from the Run Command dialog brought up SSMS 2008R2, not 2012.  Fixed the problem by editing the PATH variable, putting the path to 2012 ssms.exe ahead of the path to the 2008R2 ssms.exe.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can get [SSMS Express tools from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351) or full [SQL Server Eval tools from here](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQL2012EvalCTA/enus/default.aspx). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx)/[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx) Downloads is currently the only place to get RTM versions (*non-eval*) of the SSMS 2012 toolset.

Note the first link now(dec 2017) points to 'Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express'. ssms 2014 and 2017 are still available.

Comment: I've got the softwware - that's not the problem.  It's installing it so that I can actually see and run SSMS!

Comment: Installing 2012 DEV RTM now...should be able to tell you soon. What version did you install 2012 Express/Eval/RTM?

Comment: SSMS 2012 is installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe`

Comment: That really helps - many thanks!  It does now load, but unfortunately now comes up with an error message saying that I need to run the command ssms.exe /resetsettings from the command prompt.  I'll try variations out and be sure to add a comment back here.

Comment: Tried what was suggested: the command runs OK but has no effect on the problem.  Googling and investigation suggests that my SSMS installation hasn't worked, and I need to uninstall and try again - which I've done!  Ah well, I'll try again and report back ...

Comment: I guess you can't have both SSMS 2008 & 2012 installed at the same time?  Re-installing didn't work, so I did the following and it did:
 1. Found the SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe for 2008 and ran it via the command prompt like so: `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /action=uninstall /features=Tools`
 2. Did the same thing to uninstall 2012
 3. Restarted my computer
 3. Reinstalled SSMS 2012 using `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /action=install /features=Tools`
(idea came from - http://kushagrarakesh.blogspot.de/2012/03/issue-after-sql-server-2012-enterprise.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the command prompt installation command! I have both **SSMS 2008** and **SSMS 2012** developer versions installed. You may have had a different issue.

Comment: You can have 2008 and 2012 installed simultaneously. I have both right now. Both work fine.

Comment: I followed your first link, logged-in, filled-out the form and it just took me back to the "Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express Resources" screen. They even sent me an email thanking me for downloading it!

Comment: @PeterX - I updated the SQL 2012 [link to the Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351). They redirected the old [SQL 2012 link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763) to SQL 2014 to force users to update. ;-)

Comment: @SliverNinja, What's the difference between `110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe` and `120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe`?

Comment: 110 = SQL Server 2012, 120 = SQL Server 2014. See [related SO post regarding versions to folder path mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18754188/175679)

Answer (score 147):

Just download **SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe** from [Microsoft Downloads - SQL Server® 2012 Express with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579)

Comment: Is SQL Profiler included with this.  I remember with 2008 you didn't get Profiler when you installed the express version of Management Studio.

Comment: Yes the Express edition includes the full suite of client tools... here's a screenshot of the [setup screen](http://content.screencast.com/users/tlpm1/folders/Jing/media/92aab992-a03c-4fe7-965f-7386ebd95a27/2013-04-22_1041.png).

Comment: SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe is [NOT SSMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276167/how-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2012-ssms-express)! Confusing filename, huh? It includes only the basic management tools (e.g., Configuration Manager) and _support_ for SSMS. To install SSMS itself you need [SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/2/9/529FEF7B-2EFB-439E-A2D1-A1533227CD69/SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe). (No need to download SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe)

Comment: When you run the installer, you have to proceed as if you're going to install the entire SQL Server package, later on in the install process you can select to only install SSMS.

Comment: This simply says "SQL Server® 2012 Express".  Is this different than "SQL Server® 2008 Management Studio Express", other than the version?  I'm currently downloading "SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio with Service Pack 1 (x64)" from MSDN.

Comment: I see, it is the full server.  So is the SSMS only version exclusively available on MSDN? That seems silly.

Answer (score 87):

I just ran into this problem. I had to open back the installation for SQL Server and click **Installation** -> **New SQL server installation or add features to existing installation**. Then when we follow the instruction until we reach **feature selection**, just check the SQL Management tools checkbox and continue.

I have no idea why this software is considered a feature and hidden like this. It should be a stand-alone software installation.

Comment: Agree it should be more obvious, but many SQL Server installations wont need client tools - they will be managed from other servers.

Comment: Agree on both Shawn and Mark. But sometimes you only want the management studio.

Comment: because microsoft realized having a bunch of disparate installers caused all kinds of install / uninstall headaches.

Comment: It's been that way at least since 2008.  I remember being very confused trying to install SSMS 2008 as I only wanted the client tools, not the full server.  I learned that although the installer looks like it's going to install a full server instance initially, once you get further along it gives you the option of only installing the client tools.  Confusing as hell the first time you come across it, and not documented well (at least, not when I was installing SSMS 2008).

Answer (score 19):

I've found that the command line is my friend in these situations.

I installed the SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Management Tools, including Management Studio, off the DVD (mounted ISO actually), without installing anything else using this command:

```
e:\setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=install /FEATURES=Tools
```

Run the command prompt with elevated privileges.  And be patient, as it has to unpack the installation files.  Don't try to install the MSI files directly, as you lose the dependency checking packaged with the main installer.

Again, this is to install the full version off the Enterprise or Developer media, if you have it, and do not wish to settle for the free Express edition.

Comment: I have installed VS2010 on my machine, and later on the SQL Server 2012 (which I have read somewhere is a problematical sequence). None of the top-voted answers helped me install SSMS but yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

## Full or"Complete Management Studio" as opposed to "Express".

I was very confused at a perceived lack of Management Studio on a newly provisioned [SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) SP1 standard and enterprise edition on Azure running on Windows Server 2012.

Normally it would be found from the Start Button Shortcuts or at least in `C:\Program Files` somewhere.

Eventually, I located `C:\SQLServer_11.0_Full`, the image install path - executed and confirmed Management Studio was in fact installed by default even although it could not been seen via *Add Remove Programs*.

In short, if you provision an SQL Server 2012 VM on [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) on Azure simply run [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) and then enter `ssms.exe` to access Management Studio.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, just had the same issue on a fresh Server 2012 R2 VM.  I'd selected the Management Tools feature during SQL installation but then after the install had completed I couldn't find Management Studio anywhere.  I'd expected to see it somewhere on the start screen, but it doesn't add it here by default.  If  you press the 'down' arrow on the start menu to view all 'Apps' you can then see the SQL Server 2012 folder that would usually be in the Start>Programs menu pre-Server 2012.  Alternatively type ssms into the search.

Answer (score 10):

On the [Official SQL Server 2012 ISO that's for download](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQL2012EvalCTA/enus/default.aspx), just navigate to \x64\Setup\ (or \x86\Setup) and you will find "sql_ssms.msi".  It's only about 60 MB, and since it's an .MSI you can probably provision it to be installed automatically (say for a large lab or classroom environment).

Comment: As, @Rich in TX points out below, you have to, apparently, run it from an elevated command prompt? -- you might just right right clicking it and run as administrator -- but YMMV.

Answer (score 8):

*Late answer but could be of use to other readers*

Although SQL Server Management Studio installation is user friendly (more or less) people still seem to bump into different issues. There are lots of tutorials and instructions online, and I personally followed the ones found in this article: http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-management-studio-step-step-installation-guide/

It explains installing a standalone SSMS, but you can also install SSMS along with SQL Server – just make sure that you have selected Management Tools in the Feature selection screen.

I also recommend reading a step-by-step tutorial on installing SSMS 2008 Express after Visual Studio 2010 which can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx

It can help if you’ve just installed Visual Studio 2010 but also want to install SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 6):

After going back into the installer & checking off "Management Tools", ssms.exe was available under "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio" (thanks to everyone for pointing out where to find it).

[image: sql server setup]

Answer (score 5):

Direct MSDN link to Management Studio 2012 ONLY: [SQL Server 2012 Express Management Studio with Service Pack 1 (x64) - (English)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/subscriptions/securedownloads/hh442898#FileId=51333)

Answer (score 4):

I uninstalled all parts of SQL Server 2012 using Control Panel in Windows and then reinstalled (choosing "All Features"). Now it works!

Answer (score 4):

I found it here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

This did not require any TechNet rigamarole or the use of their horrible Java 7 based download manager.

Comment: Just for the record, that link goes to the download of SQL Server 1012 Express, which includes the SSMS Express version. This is not the same as the full SSMS, which may (or may not) be what the OP or anyone else needs.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: What does the full SSMS include that the SSMS 2012 Express lacks?  I installed the Express version and was surprised to see it included SQL Profiler, the Activity Monitor and standard reports, such as the All Blocking Transactions report.  I note the Activity Monitor doesn't work with an instance of SQL 2008 R2 but I'm not sure if that is something to do with Express or whether SSMS didn't install properly (it appears in my tool bar without a logo of any kind, suggesting something may have gone a little wrong during install).

Comment: @Mordachai I went for that one aswell - the other site didnt even seem to work properly!  I ended up consulting [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) which (at time of writing) had information about which of the cryptically named installers I should download.  Maybe they are trying to emulate the horror you experience when trying to find an installer for oracle products?

Answer (score 3):

For separate modules (x86 and x64), if you want a customized installation without downloading loads of crap, see *[Servers
Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=29062)*.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded it [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686) (named 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools'). In this version you will get a [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) installation with the functionality to manage the [SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012) server.

Answer (score 0):

Select SQL Management Studio from the dropdown in *[Download SQL Server 2012 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPNOCTAV2/enus/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Install SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU for x64 bit version from here and choose to install all components. This installs SQL Server Management Studio. You can also install Reporting Services with this installation.

/*Express with Advanced Services (contains the database engine, Express Tools, Reporting Services, and Full Text Search)*/

Download Link:
    http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to be the latest 2014 and 2012 SQL Server Management Studio releases here [Previous SQL Server Management Studio Releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238488.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell and type:

```
gci -Path "C:\Program Files*\Microsoft SQL Server" -Recurse -Include "Ssms.exe" | Select -ExpandProperty FullName
```