# How to install SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (SSMS) Express?

Tags: sql-server, database, installation, ssms

I just installed **SQL Server 2012 Express**, I can connect with database from **`VS2012RC`**.

Database is working :) I use **`Win7 SP1 64bit`**.

**[I download program from page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)**
I choose `ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe`

I want to install **Management Studio 2012**, but after unpack installer has stopped. I see only for moment some console application.

1. What could be cause?
2. Where can I find any log file?

Comment: Try to find any associated log files.

Comment: But where? After "instalation" immediately unpacked files are deleted. There is no log file in folder with installator.

Comment: Management Studio or Management Studio Express? Where did you get the installer? Have you searched your system for a folder called `Setup Bootstrap`? This is where the log files should be...

Comment: Ad1) I can't find folder "Setup Bootstrap". It's in root folder c:\Windows??

Comment: Ad2) I have Management Studio. I think if I had wrong version, I will probably get message "You have wrong version"...

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid :/ <br/>Could you give my link to download Management Studio for Windows 7 SP1 64bit for MS SQL 2012

Comment: +1 because the problem still exists.=D

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to install [ENU\x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) which is Express with Tools (RTM release. SP1 release can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx)).

As the page states

> Express with Tools (with LocalDB) Includes the database engine and SQL
>   Server Management Studio Express) This package contains everything
>   needed to install and configure SQL Server as a database server.
>   Choose either LocalDB or Express depending on your needs above.

So install this and use the management studio included with it.

Comment: I installed it :) SSMS =Sql Server Management Studio, thanks for you advice

Comment: Ridiculous that Microsoft couldn't document better. Thanks!

Comment: Management Studio doesn't seem to be included with the SQL Server Express 2012 installs (64bit) as of May 2017

I've tried to install it twice from scratch but I can't see the Management Studio installed nor can I see the "Management Tools Basic" option during installation (Doug's Answer below)

You need to see Greg Bray's other answer below to download Management Studio separately from the link he provided. I haven't been able to google a download link and this is the only one I've managed to find.

Answer (score 34):

When I installed:
ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

I had to choose the following options to get the management Tools:

1. "New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation."
2. "Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2012"
3. Accept the license.
4. Check the box for "Management Tools - Basic".
5. Wait a long time as it installs.

When I was done I had an option "SQL Server Management Studio" within my Start Menu.

Searching for "Management" pulled it up faster within the Start Menu.

Comment: You need to install this way if you want to use the profiler or the ssdt features these days.

Comment: Your answer is better because it actually tells how to get the SSMS installed onto a computer. Your solution allowed me to install the Management Studio without creating a SQL instance that I would have to maintain.

Answer (score 14):

You can download the 32bit or 64bit version of "Express With Tools" or "SQL Server Management Studio Express" (SSMSE tools only) from:

https://web.archive.org/web/20170507040411/https://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPNOCTAV2/enus/default.aspx

This link is for SQL Server 2012 Express Service Pack 1 released 11/09/2012 (11.0.3000.00)
The original RTM release was 11.0.2100.60 from March or May of 2012.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Good evening,

The previous clues to get SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe runing didn't work as stated for me. After a while of searching, trying, retrying again and again, I finally figured it out.
When executing SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe on my Windows seven system, I kept runing into compatibility issues. The trick is to run SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe in compatibility mode with Windows XP SP2.
Edit the installer properties and enable compatibility mode with XP (service pack 2), then you'll be able to access Mr Doug (answered Mar 4 at 15:09) resolution.

Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way to install MSSQL 2012
                         MS SQL INSTALLATION

Here i am showing the easiest way to install ms sql 2012.

My opinion is the installation will be easier with windows 8.1 rather than windows 7.

This is my personnal opinion only.

We can install in windows 7 as well.

The steps to be followed:

Download any one of the link using the following URL

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe or SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe or SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

Right click on .exe file and run it

We should leave everything default while installing.

During installation, there will be 2 options:

1)If you are New user,then click on new sql-server stand alone application.

2)If you have already MS SQL application then you can upgrade by using the other option.

Then accept the Licence terms and click Next.

Now you will move on to Product Updates and press next then Setup support rules.

After this Feature selection.According to me we can check all the boxes except localdb.

Next it will take you to Instance Configuration where you should select Named Instance as

"SQLEXPRESS".

Then go to Server Configuration and press next.

Now Database engine configuration:

Authentication Mode:we can click on any one that is windows authentication mode or mixed.

Windows authentication mode (default for windows).

Mixed authentication mode:then should create username and password.

Then move on Error reporting,we can move further by clicking next to install process.

Finally we can see the Complete windows by showing the products added .

We can close and run the MSSQL server.

I hope it's useful.

Regards

Ramya