# Installation of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am attempting to download and install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 onto a Windows XP machine (hence the need for the 2008 version). The download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7593) is successful, and leaves an executable `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe`.

Running this executable unpacks files into a local directory on the D: drive, and a console application box momentarily appears, but the files on the D: drive are then deleted and nothing else happens. I cannot find an error log anywhere.

This appears to the same problem as [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276167/how-to-install-sql-server-management-studio-2012-ssms-express?s=9%7C3.9180), but 2012 cannot be run on a machine running XP, so none of the links are helping any.

Edit: The version of Windows is XP 5.2 Service Pack 3.

Comment: Looked in `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup
Bootstrap\Log\`

Comment: Is the machine Windows XP Home, or Pro, or 64bit or ???

Comment: The log file Alex pointed out should have an answer. But - assuming your system is actually 32-bit, and not x64 - you can also run `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe /x` to just extract the files, then you can run setup.exe interactively. You might get more clues about failures this way (but again, the log will have the details).

Comment: @AlexK., thank you for the tip; there are no files in that directory.

Comment: Also, if you extract the files first using `/x`, you can then run `setup /Q /ACTION=install /Features=Tools` and hopefully a quiet install with no UI will bypass whatever problem is hanging you up. (I suspect it might be that you need to reboot your computer first - that was what happened to me the last time I tried to install quietly. But that problem *was* logged in `Setup Bootstrap\Log`.)