# Where is SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

Ive installed the sql 2012 configuration - all worked fine. 
but the management studio does not install properly.

<strike>I have attached an image.</strike> Trying to click the reuslt, and I get this strange file , instead of openning the SQL interface.
thanks for you help

Comment: What is the link to the image?

Comment: The image was not attached.. You may not have enough reputation to do so. Now Management studio is one of the features that can be installed. Ensure that management studio is part of the selected features.

Comment: Did you install SQL Server Management Studio? If not, why do you expect SQL Server Management Studio to be installed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is SQL Server Management Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452851/where-is-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which installer / version you used, it might have not included the Management Studio by default and hence, this will need to be installed separately.

You can find the install from this [Microsoft link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

From here, if it is only Management Studio you wanting - select only that.

[image]

Download and install.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is common to expect Management Studio to come installed with SQL Server 2012.  I also expected it to come bundled.

I just finished installing SQL Management Studio from a SQL Server 2012 installation.  You just have to select the feature.  It showed up under Shared Features for me.