# ssms.exe /resetsetting not a valid command

Tags: windows-installer, ssms-2012

When I open SQL Server Management Studio 2012 running on Windows Server 2012R2 Datacenter in Azure I get the following error. 
    "A problem occured while loading the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio menu. To fix this problem run 'Ssms.exe /resetsettings' from the command prompt. Note: this command resets your environment settings."
     [ssms.exe error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0usr.jpg)
I have attempted the following corrective actions.

1.) run ssms.exe /resetsettings . This is not a valid command.

2.) Repair and uninstall. The repair and uninstall attempt produced the exact same error message which I have listed below.

2.1) "Error details:§ Error installing SQL Server Advanced Tools Error code: 1648"

2.2) The error log file contains the following.

2.2.1) Detailed results:
       Feature:            Management Tools - Complete
       Status:                        **Failed**: see logs for details
       Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process
                                      of the feature.
       Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve 
                                      the error, and then try the setup process
                                      again.
      Component name:                SQL Server Advanced Tools
      Component error code:          1648

2.2.1.1) The Component log file sql_tools_loc_Cpu64_1033_1.log following error.

2.2.1.1.1) ******* Product: {6B3840D6-4B8F-4E74-9202-9CE36DA94E99}
******* Action: 
******* CommandLine: **********
 Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
 Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (F4:E4) [08:58:17:537]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
 MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
 End dialog not enabled
 Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\49b14f8.msi
Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\49b14f8.msi
APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
 APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
 APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{6B3840D6-4B8F-4E74-9202-9CE36DA94E99}'.
APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\429b8ec.msp'.
SequencePatches starts. Product code: {6B3840D6-4B8F-4E74-9202-9CE36DA94E99}, Product version: 11.0.2100.60, Upgrade code: {DC4BA39C-A84E-4A04-A045-F97F76CB6351}, Product language 1033
**Note: 1: 2219 
***PATCH SEQUENCER ERROR: failed to open summary info from storage for Target01ToUpgrade01 transform in {23A27D51-CAA5-4121-A78D-701A27B8626D} patch!*** (1: 2219 )****
SequencePatches returns error 1648.
Note: 1: 1708 
**Product: SQL Server 2012 Client Tools -- Installation failed.**

#

I believe that root cause is an issue with Windows Installer. My knowledge and experience with Windows Installer is very limited.

I have reviewed the following articles and/or blogs. I have attempted their suggested corrective actions. None of them have worked.

1.) https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/795182/ssms-2012-will-not-open-using-run-as

2.) [Where is SQL Server Management Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452851/where-is-sql-server-management-studio-2012)

**What is the corrective action for "A problem occured while loading the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio menu. To fix this problem run 'Ssms.exe /resetsettings' from the command prompt. Note: this command resets your environment settings."?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I found the Microsoft tool diagnose and fix program installing and uninstalling problems automatically troubleshooter. You can download it from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971187 .
     I used the tool to uninstall multiple entries for SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and SQL Server Management Tools 2012. I was then able to reinstall the management tools. SQL Server Management Studio 2012 now runs with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

In the article [SQL Server Management Studio Reset Settings](https://thethriftyspartans.com/sql-server-management-studio-reset-settings/), the author mentions the folder:

```
C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio
```

I've found it, and within the folder there were two files with a fresh modified date:

- `Design_qgmmzmc4.4u4.winprf`
- `SqlStudio.bin`

I renamed these and tried to start the SSMS again, but nothing changed, so investigated some more and found *another* hidden file:

```
C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\\[languageid]\Ssms.CTM"
```

After deleting (or renaming) this file, the SSMS service could start normally again.